# Table Master and details with same foreign django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create two models in django, Reservation and DetailsReservation, i need that models has a same userReservation .Example if i create a Reservation with id: 1 and User: 4, when create a Details with Reservation 1, should copy user in userbyReserva

```
   class Reservation(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        userReservation = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)   

class DetailsReservation(models.Model):
    Reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    userbyReserva = #same user that do reservate
```

Comment: You can override the `save()` method but why do you need this? You can access the user by traversing the relations, i.e. `user = details_reservation.reservation.userreservation`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the user through the `Reservation` using a method as property. This is the easiest way to do that.

Some notes about the code:

1. always use a lower case name for the fields and without the camelNaming.
2. Avoid plurals on the models' name.
3. I would avoid using `default=1` in a ForeignKey. Better raise an error if the relation is not set. (What happen if the User=1 is deleted?)
4. Do not copy the data if not necessary, you can use properties to access related field. The user is available only if a reservation is related to the `DetailReservation` object; `detail_reservation.user` will return None if the reservation is not set.
5. I don't understand why you created the `reservation` relation optional from `DetailReservation`.

Have a look

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )

class DetailReservation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, blank=False, related_name='details',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    @property
    def user(self):
        return reservation.user if reservation else return None
```